# Changing Open With default program and "the file cannot be accessed by the system" error

Tags: windows

I have written a .sh file and I want to run it in Windows terminal by double clicking on it.

Todo so, I follow;

**.sh file > Right click > Properties > Opens with: > Change > Look for another app on this PC >**

Then browsing into

**"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"**

selecting the wt.exe file throws:

**"the file cannot be accessed by the system"**

error. Why I can not select Windows Terminal wt.exe file to be used with a .sh file? How can I fix this problem? I tried to run explorer.exe as admin but still could not select wt.exe with same error.